# what is the meaning of (font:4em/50px) in css?

Tags: css

I am confused in `font:4em/50px` in css class.

In my HTML `<div class="typed">kupendra</div>`

But i am confused at in css class.

```
.typed {
    font: 4em/50px;
}
```

So what is the meaning of font: `4em/50px;`

Comment: `4em/50px` means `4` times the current size over `50px`. For Instance, if current size is `20px` then the result would be `80px/50px`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax is just short-hand for specifying the `font-size` and `line-height`. Here's how it would look if you declared the rules manually:

```
.typed {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS font property is a shorthand for all these:

```
font-family:
font-size:
line-height:
font-style:
font-weight:
...more...
```

This example is the minimum that you can assign to the shorthand **font** property: `font: 4em/50px Helvetica;` and it's a shorthand for:

```
font-size: 4em;
line-height: 50px;
font-family: Helvetica;
```

Please note that the slash character `/` doesn't mean division and it simply separates the `font-size` & `line-height` values.

Check out these links for more info:

- http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/